# Problem with lightning:input component. Onchange event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to use "lightning:input" components (still in beta) but I encounter an issue when the component is firing the onchange event :

> Something has gone wrong. Underlying raw object [object Object] does not support property: currentTarget
> Failing descriptor: {c$testComponents$controller$sayHello}.
>   Please try again.

**cmp**

```
<lightning:input type="text" value="test" name="inputText" label="Input" onchange="{!c.sayHello}"/>
```

**controller**

```
sayHello : function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('Hello');
}
```

Does anyone have a workaround which works with this component ?

Thank you !

Comment: Instead of onchage use --> oninput i hope this will work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. This is a known problem that is currently being worked on. In the meantime, you can work around the issue by binding a change handler to the `value` attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="value" type="String" />
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.value}" action="{!c.onValueChange}" />
<lightning:input type="text" value="{!v.value}" />
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene. ( I'm sad we don't have an updateOn attribute anymore because this workaround is only working with keyup events on text inputs...)
Do you you have a link where we can track the fix for this ?

Comment: Hey Lucas--what use case is this workaround not working for?

Comment: If I want my action to only be triggered on blur instead of keyup with input text for example

Comment: This Doesn't work if your lightning:input tag is inside aura:iteration@EugeneKashida

Answer (score 2):

I have faced some errors before too and I find it generally easier to work with `event.getSource()` which returns the input component. On it you can use the usual `get` method on components:

```xml
<lightning:input type="text"
                 value="{!v.value}"
                 name="inputName"
                 onchange="{! c.onChange }" />
```

```js
onChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    const inputName = event.getSource().get('v.name');
    const inputValue = event.getSource().get('v.value');
    // ...
}
```