# Component set() does not work on lightning:inputField if user changes the field value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-inputfield

I'm finding the `component.set` method only works on `lightning:inputField` components when the user has not changed the value in that field.  See code example below.

Component:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm"  objectApiName="Account" recordId="0010G00002JEU4OQAX" > 
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Rating" onchange="{!c.setDemoValue}" />
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="nom" fieldName="Name" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Controller:

`({
    setDemoValue : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('before value: ', component.find('nom').get('v.value'));
        component.find("nom").set("v.value", "temp");
        console.log('after value: ', component.find('nom').get('v.value'));
    }
})`

If you change the "Rating" once, you can see the code work as expected.  In the javascript console you can see it log out:

```
before value:
after value: temp
```

Now change the Name field from "temp" to "hello world", and change the rating again.

```
before value: hello world
after value: hello world
```

This seems like a defect to me (I would expect after value to be "temp"), but im not sure if there is a workaround or if I am doing something wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: have you tried by setting  a value attribute to the field?

Comment: yeah -- still see the issue

Comment: i saw a different post where the recommendation was to use to change hanlder with inputfield. just an alternate suggestion to see if this can help you move on.https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142908/problem-with-lightninginput-component-onchange-event/145111

Comment: @Phil Rymek, what is your specific use case? why would  you want to overide what the user enters in a field while they change it in the layout, or after? (out of curiosity) if its the later, why not just set the field value onsubmit ?

Comment: Thanks Rao.  I had difficulty even getting the aura:handler to fire for a lightning:inputField.  @glls I have a couple use cases this is blocking.  A user changing the selected country on the form should blank out the address field.  Or checking "Same address as earlier" in a checkbox and having it overwrite what the user may have written with an address entered earlier in the form.

Comment: were you able to hack around the issue?

Comment: Not yet but I will work towards it and use a solution like the one you described below.  Thanks for your help.  Spoke with SFDC and they believe this is working as intended, as a mechanism to prevent you from overwriting user data.  Seems like there should be a function you can call to overwrite this, like a "clean()" or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the prettiest of workarounds, but, due to a similar problem I had faced in the past, I ended up hiding the inputFields `display:none` and using lightning:input fields when I rendered my component.

For example:

```
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Subject" style="display:none;"/>
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Description" style="display:none;"/>


    <lightning:input aura:id="test"  label="Subject" name="Case Subject" onblur="{!c.itemsChange}"/>

    <lightning:textarea label="Description" name="Case Description" maxlength="300" onblur="{!c.itemsChange}"/>

    <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Clear" name="Clear" onchange="{!c.clear}"/>
```

and in my controller, i simply do what one would expect to work with a lightning:inputField

```
clear :  function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("test").set("v.value", "");
},
```

Since the above 'leaves my inputFields hidden and unmodified, I actually have to populate the fieldnames on form submit:

```
handleRecordSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
    event.getParams().fields.FIELDNAME = 'the lightning:input field value';
}
```

for what its worth, I know there are multiple known issues with the lighting:recordEdit form, and I wouldnt be surprised if this becomes one of them:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?search=lightning%3AinputField

Looks like a similar known issue to :

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mDOkQAM